# VBA to show message box if update query changes 1 row, show another if none

Tags: vba, ms-access, sql-update, msgbox

I'm working on running an append query (to change someones login password) in access, currently it checks to make sure the password matches and that they knew the original password. However, I run into a problem where if the update query: `DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE Credentials SET Credentials.[Password] = [Forms]![LoginSubmit]![DesiredPassword] WHERE (((Credentials.Password)=[Forms]![LoginSubmit]![CurrentPassword]) AND ((Credentials.[User ID])=[Forms]![LoginSubmit]![User ID]));"` updates 0 rows (meaning that the conditions were not met) it closes (I have a `docmd.close` following). If it does update their password it does the same, so in the end you don't know if it was successful until you try your new password.

I would like to know when it updates 0 rows so I can shoot up a MsgBox telling them it didn't work, end the sub and have them try again. If it updates 1 row I would have a MsgBox say "Success".

I know the VBA to the above except for the part that returns a value for the amount of updated rows in that query. Could someone help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute your `UPDATE` statement from a `DAO.Database` object variable.  Afterward you can base your user notice on the variable's `RecordsAffected` property.

Here is a simple example, verified with Access 2007.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim strUpdate As String
strUpdate = "UPDATE tblFoo" & vbCrLf & _
    "SET some_text = 'bar'" & vbCrLf & _
    "WHERE id = 7;"
Debug.Print strUpdate
Set db = CurrentDb
db.Execute strUpdate, dbFailOnError
MsgBox db.RecordsAffected & " records affected"
Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: I'm getting and expected parameters not met error (expects 3, given 2 on `db.Execute strUpdate, dbFailOnError`)

Comment: I added `Debug.Print strUpdate`.  Use that to print the `UPDATE` statement to the Immediate window.  Go there (Ctrl+g), copy the statement, and paste it into SQL View of a new Access query.  When you try to run that query, Access will inform you what it thinks is the "missing parameter".

Comment: `Private Sub LoginSubmit_Click()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim strUpdate As String
strUpdate = "UPDATE Credentials" & vbCrLf & _
"SET Credentials.[Password] = [Forms]![LoginSubmit]![DesiredPassword]" & vbCrLf & _
    "WHERE (((Credentials.Password)=[Forms]![LoginSubmit]![CurrentPassword]) AND ((Credentials.[User ID])=[Forms]![LoginSubmit]![User ID]));"
Set db = CurrentDb
db.Execute strUpdate, [dbFailOnError]
MsgBox db2.RecordsAffected & " records affected"
Set db = Nothing

End Sub` - this is my code

Comment: Super weird, i put the query from the immediate window into a new query and it shows no problem - no errors nothing.

Comment: Remove the square brackets surrounding `dbFailOnError`.  What is `db2` in `db2.RecordsAffected`?

Comment: I had removed the brackets, the db2 is removed (I was just checking to see if by renaming db to db2 i could circumvent the error, it looks like I failed to rename `db2.recordsaffected` back to `db.recordsaffected` appologies - same error exists.

Comment: Could anything have to do with the fact the query can't check credentials.password through VBA since the field on the table has the password input mask? (It can however through a SQL query done trhough the query design/sql view)

Comment: I don't think so, but you could try removing the input mask temporarily and see if it changes anything.

Comment: Solved the problem to show the message box - The query had to be as such: `"UPDATE Credentials" & " SET Credentials.[Password] =" & "'[Forms]![LoginSubmit]![DesiredPassword]'" & " WHERE (((Credentials.Password)=" & "'[Forms]![LoginSubmit]![CurrentPassword])'" & " AND ((Credentials.[User ID])=" & "'[Forms]![LoginSubmit]![User ID]')))"`

Comment: Can I use the value of recordsaffected as a condition? Like `If db.Recordsaffected=0 then...` I've tried to no avail.

Comment: That should be possible.  But that issue sounds to me like it should be a new question.